# Listening to Port 1880 fails on Windows

Tags: node.js, windows, networking, server

I am not able to start a server listening to port 1880. I tried this simple code in Node.js:

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
      res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
      res.write('Hello World!');
      res.end();
}).listen(1880);
```

Which gives me the following error:

```
Error: listen EACCES: permission denied 0.0.0.0:1880
[90m    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1283:19)[39m
[90m    at listenInCluster (net.js:1348:12)[39m
[90m    at Server.listen (net.js:1436:7)[39m
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\mmueller\Desktop\test\test.js:6:4)
[90m    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:956:30)[39m
[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:973:10)[39m
[90m    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:812:32)[39m
[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)[39m
[90m    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:10)[39m
[90m    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11[39m
Emitted 'error' event on Server instance at:
[90m    at emitErrorNT (net.js:1327:8)[39m
[90m    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)[39m {
  code: [32m'EACCES'[39m,
  errno: [32m'EACCES'[39m,
  syscall: [32m'listen'[39m,
  address: [32m'0.0.0.0'[39m,
  port: [33m1880[39m
}
```

What I tried:

- Checked if there is another program listening on this port (which is
  not the case)
- Executed command in admin console
- Disabled windows firewall
- Disabled Kaspersky tools

Still no success. 
With port 1881 it also doesn't work. So some port-range has no access.
But with e.g. port 18800 it works.

What else can I do to figure out why I don't have access to listen to port 1880? What else could be blocking this port access if not firewall or anti virus software?

Answer (score 2):

I have found the issue: Hyper-V was reserving some ports on windows.

```
netsh int ip show excludedportrange protocol=tcp
```

[image]